# C++ DLL return string array, who should allocate the memory and how?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dll, wrapper

I'm writing a c++/cli (warpper-)dll to use a C# Dll in native C++.
One of the C# functions I'm wrapping returns a String-array **of unknown size**.
I had the idea of using an export function like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void someFunc(char*** pStringArray);
```

With the idea in mind to pass a char*-array-pointer to the Dll. The Dll will fill the passed array with C# String-array.

I don't know the size of the returned string array so I can't allocate memory to the pointer before calling the Dll function. Although it feels bad to allocate the memory on the heap within the Dll, because this could easy lead to a big memory leak. If possible, i want to avoid clearing the memory with another Dll call.

**What is the best practice for this problem?**

Are there better ways to return a string array of unknown size?

Comment: @AlexF I had the same thought but this sounds pretty ugly to me. I hope there is a better way.

Comment: There isn't.  Look at some of the Win32API functions that need to allocate a buffer, they follow one of (3) patterns: (1) a function to free the memory; or (2) the caller allocates the buffer and passes an in/out size parameter and the function returns "not enough buffer" with the size parameter containing the requires size; or (3) the COM convention of `CoTaskMemAlloc` / `CoTaskMemFree`

Comment: A SAFEARRAY of BSTR will solve your problem (it might not be worth the added complexity, though)